# Exporting Oracle Database Schema Through Command Line As Type Files

Tags: sql, database, oracle, command-line, export

The only method of exporting a schema through the command line/.bat, that I can find, gives a .dmp or .sql output.  I'm looking for a way to export a schema as a folder of type files.

I normally do this in SQL Developer through the Export Wizard and selecting Type Files under Save As.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you want?

Comment: For example, using DataPump or the original Export utility you can export a database through the command line as a .sql or .dmp, but I need a folder of type files.  I'm wondering if it is possible to get the same output as using the Export Wizard in SQL Developer and selecting Type Files as the output, but through a command line interface.  If so, how?

Comment: The part I am not understanding is what you mean by "folder of type files". Do you mean ascii files that are either delimited or fixed length? Ones that contain the table rows and not the definitions?